# X10 code does not recognize the second core of the CPU

Tags: multicore, x10-language

I wrote a canonical "Hello, World" demo class in X10:

```
class Hello {
  public static def main(args:Rail[String]):void {    
     finish for (p in Place.places()) {
        at (p) async Console.OUT.println(here+" says hello");
     }
     Console.OUT.println("Goodbye");
  }
}
```

My computer has a 2-core CPU, but X10 code does not recognize two processing cores. As I understand, it recognizes one core of the CPU only. So, the output to console is as follows:

```
Place(0) says hello
Goodbye
```

instead of

```
Place(0) says hello
Place(1) says hello
Goodbye
```

as it might be expected to be.

How to force X10 code to recognize all processing cores of the CPU available on my laptop?
My laptop is equipped with an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU. The operating system is Windows 7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, X10 will only start a single place regardless of how many physical cores are available.  (In fact, depending on your application it may be better to run a single place for each multi-core CPU, and use `async` to take advantage of multithreaded parallelism within a place.

To request a different number of places, either set the environment variable `X10_NPLACES` or use the `-np` option to the `x10` launcher, i.e.

```
X10_NPLACES=2 x10 Hello
x10 -np 2 Hello
```